# Error and Success Handling in JQuery Ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

how can i handle error and success messages in Ajax? I have an ajax call where my datas are saved into a db. My php script first checked if a user have x amount. if he has less then x then he should fire a alert (amount < x) Else insert into db.

my php file:

```
 ...
 .....
 if ($wallet_amount < "100") {
     $wa1 = 0;
     echo $wa1;
 } else {
     $inito = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO bs (title, start, end, userid, typ, code) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :pid, :col, :code)");
     $inito->bindValue(':pid', $pid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $inito->bindValue(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $inito->bindValue(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $inito->bindValue(':end', $end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $inito->bindValue(':col', $col, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $inito->bindValue(':code', $code, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $inito->execute();

     exit();        
}
```

My js file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'add.php',
    data: {
        'title': $('#Name').val(), 
        'start': start, 
        'end': $('#End').val(), 
        'code': $('input[name="code"]:checked').val()
    },
    type: "POST",
    error: function () {
        alert('There was an error while adding events.');
    }
});
```

My first try goes wrong. I write something like that:

```
 success: function (response) {
            if (response === 0) {
                alert("Amount < X!");
            } else if (response === 1) {
                alert("Amount > X);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('There was an error while adding events.');
        }
```

Comment: I assume the missing `"` is just a copy-paste error. What response do you see in the console? Also note that you don't output anything in your php script in case of success.

Comment: `typeof(response)` is string or number? i guess you should check with `if (response === '0') {`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess in success block you have used a strict check `===`, this checks the type and value both:

```
success: function (response) {
        if (response === '0') { // update this 
            alert("Amount < X!");
        } else if (response === '1') {
            alert("Amount > X"); //<---quote is missing i guess it's just a typo.
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('There was an error while adding events.');
    }
```

---

Also i am not sure if this check `} else if (response === '1') {` would ever happen because i don't see if you get `'1'` in the response.

Answer (score 1):

To make the code a little more cleaner, I would suggest you start by returning the values with json (even if it is only one variable)

So the PHP look like

**php**

```
/* ... */
echo json_encode(array('wal' => $wal));
/* ... */
```

Next, in your ajax code, you need to read it correctly. E.g.

**ajax**

```
success: function(response) {
    var wal = response.wal
    if (wal == 0) {
        alert("Amount < X!");
    } else if (wal == 1) {
        alert("Amount > X);
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Try that, and as Jai said, only check for the value, and not for the type (x == 0 instead of x === 0)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use the content of your respone to switch your error and success cases. Think about different status codes like status code `200` or `204` on success and status code `400` on error for example. Than, you can also code a more type-safe application with explicit return values:

```
$.ajax({
  statusCode: {
    404: function() {
      alert( "page not found" );
    }
  }
});
```